# Unity does not detect or open external script editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, unity-editor

I install Unity Hub 3.2.0 and Unity 2021.3.35f1. Then I tried to change external script editor to VS2019, but the unity option didn't show any external editors. So I added manually `devenv.exe` file with `browe...` option but it still not works. No editor works when I trying to open the script. Literally nothing happens.

In another example, if user add a path, it shows like `Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 [version]` but in my project it shows like `Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 (internal)`. I couldn't find a case like this.

[image]

How can I connect unity to VS2019?

Comment: would going to VS 2022 be an option for you? Not sure if that solves the issue directly but possible that there is some version support "issue" ... alternatively, what happens if you go for `Browse...` and find your VS installation manually?

Comment: tried https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: what goes wrong with the visual studio one - i had to do that before and it didnt cause me an issue

Comment: @derHugo I've already tried with Unity 2022.3.20 and VS2022, nothing changed. the same problems happen.
above screenshot, listed VS2019 and VS code is what I added by `Browse...`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I don't have no Idea.. VS doesn't seem to make a problem.

Comment: Have you setup Visual Studio to run as admin? That might be the reason why the editor isn't launching, if Unity isn't configured to run as admin.